# Graphql subscription lost after few hours

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync, react-apollo-hooks

I have made a subscription in aws appsync for sending notification to the react client. I am calling the subscription using lambda. It works fine but subscription stops after 2-3 hours and I need to then refresh the client application to make subscription active agian. On client I'm using useSubscription hook.
I need to initiate subscription again or setTimeout /keep alive so that subscription should not stop working.

I am using aws SNS to send notification to the clients.
I did not find any error in SNS logs.

Comment: Why don't you use firebase SDK and lambda for sending notifications?

Comment: What client are you using? The AppSync SDK sends pings to keep the connection alive.

Comment: I'm using apollo  client.